# Move folder before install in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to make something in Inno Setup : move folder (if they exist due to a precedent install) to an another folder before install and replace it after install. I need it because they are user files/folders and must keep them later.

Fot the moment, i make this script (just for before install) that doesn't work (make some warning "could not call proc") :

```
[Code]
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if DirExists(ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}\FolderCopy\')) then
  begin
    // move file
    FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}\FolderCopy\*'),ExpandConstant('{cf}\FolderCopy\*'), True);
  end;
end;
```

I started in the section inno setup code, so can you help me ?

I've search on web (and this website) but I have not found a satisfactory solution. I've not found some function like "FileCopy" for folder too...

Thanks

Comment: The firt thing is that you don't specify which `Step` you want to change, e.g. `if CurStep=ssPostInstall then`

Comment: Ok i will try that first. And is there a way to copy a folder instead a file in Inno Setup ?